# changing date in a log

Tags: bash, sed

today I have this file:
`a20 is (off) Jan 15` and I turned into this: 
`a20 is (on) Jan 16` 
but the second date is whatever day the a script runs

`date=$(date)`
with this sed commands:

`sed -i '/'$1'/ s/off/on/' /home/josepas/Mantenimiento`

`sed -i '/'$1'/ s/).*/) /' /home/josepas/Mantenimiento`

`sed -i "/$1/ s/$/$date/g" /home/josepas/Mantenimiento`

I want to make this a single sed that searches for the line that starts with a(somenumber) I heard about the option -e for multiple sed commands, hope you can help me

Comment: Do you want to change `Jan 31` to `Feb 1`? What about `Feb 28` -> `Feb 29` or `Mar 1`?

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you:

```
date="Jan 16"
echo "a20 is (off) Jan 15" |
sed '/^a[0-9]*/s/(off).*/(on) '"$date"'/'
a20 is (on) Jan 16
```

if you want to use the "tomorrow date" and you're using GNU sed, then:

```
echo "a20 is (off) Jan 15" | 
sed '/^a[0-9]\+/s/^\(.*\)(off) \(.*\)/echo "\1(on) $(date -d '\''\2 tomorrow'\'' '\''+%b %d'\'')"/e'
a20 is (on) Jan 16
```

Comment: That answer hurt my thinker.  For anyone just wanting tomorrow's date, you can use this (and loop for as many tomorrows as you like)  D=$( date -d "$D tomorrow" +'%b %d' ); echo $D

Answer (score 1):

You could concatenate `s` commands with `;` and do some grouping by surrounding your commands with `{`/`}`. e.g.:

```
echo -e "a20 is (off) Jan 15\na21 is (off) Jan 15" | sed "/a20/ { s/off/on/; s/).*/) /; s/$/$(date)/ }"
```